# why threre are some query that has elapsed larger than max_execution_time?

Tags: clickhouse

I use clickhouse_sqlalchemy to connect to clickhouse and timeout has been set, but it looks like the timeout is not taking effect because I can often find the following query:

```
select elapsed, query, ProfileEvents, Settings from system.processes where elapsed>10\G;



Row 1:
──────
elapsed:              22.066440963
query:                SELECT * FROM A WHERE toDate(A."Time") = '2023-05-26' FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNamesAndTypes
ProfileEvents:        {'Query':1,'SelectQuery':1,'ReadBufferFromFileDescriptorReadBytes':528770,'ReadCompressedBytes':528319,'CompressedReadBufferBlocks':48,'CompressedReadBufferBytes':3044524,'OpenedFileCacheHits':14,'IOBufferAllocs':37,'IOBufferAllocBytes':12735376,'FunctionExecute':32,'MarkCacheHits':14,'CreatedReadBufferOrdinary':14,'DiskReadElapsedMicroseconds':358,'NetworkReceiveElapsedMicroseconds':9948,'NetworkReceiveBytes':1122,'SelectedParts':2,'SelectedRanges':2,'SelectedMarks':5,'SelectedRows':29454,'SelectedBytes':4880428,'WaitMarksLoadMicroseconds':59,'ContextLock':64,'RWLockAcquiredReadLocks':2,'RealTimeMicroseconds':9852,'UserTimeMicroseconds':6895,'SystemTimeMicroseconds':134,'SoftPageFaults':1108,'OSCPUVirtualTimeMicroseconds':7024,'OSWriteBytes':4096,'OSReadChars':542614,'OSWriteChars':4470,'CannotWriteToWriteBufferDiscard':90,'QueryProfilerRuns':88,'ThreadPoolReaderPageCacheMiss':15,'ThreadPoolReaderPageCacheMissBytes':528770,'ThreadPoolReaderPageCacheMissElapsedMicroseconds':358}
Settings:             {'max_query_size':'8589934592','receive_timeout':'10','send_timeout':'10','load_balancing':'random','http_send_timeout':'10','http_receive_timeout':'10','max_execution_time':'10','readonly':'2','max_memory_usage':'64424509440'}
```

elapsed is 22, which is larger than 'max_execution_time':'10', why is this happening?

I can't open query_thread_log right now so I don't know what happened in threads.

I also tried running the query manually at the same time, result is returned quickly(21740 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.135 sec. Processed 29.45 thousand rows, 4.88 MB (217.92 thousand rows/s., 36.11 MB/s.))

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

"ClickHouse checks the restrictions for data parts, not for each row. It means that you can exceed the value of restriction with the size of the data part."

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity

It's counterintuitive (somewhat) but this on the part level not the row level.

In addition, at this time, it is not checked for one of the sorting stages, or when merging and finalizing aggregate functions.

With that all said, the HUGE difference between sql-alchemy and -client is worrisome. I'd recommend opening an issue in the GitHub repo for sql-alchemy.